# Is there logical short-circuiting in the C preprocessor?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

The [gcc docs for cpp](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html) explain about the `#if` directive:

> [...] and logical operations (&& and ||). The latter two obey the usual short-circuiting rules of standard C.

What does that mean? There is no evaluation of expressions during preprocessing, so how can it be short-circuited?

Comment: I think here, short-circuit means not evaluating the second term if the evaluation of the first term is fully determining the resulting value

Comment: But how can you tell?  Why would this matter?

Comment: The preprocessor expressions are of course evaluated. The C code is not evaluated.

Comment: In standard C, `#if` only wants a constant expression. If that constant expression is `my_const1 && my_const2` then the expression is evaluated as it would have been anywhere else in the code, simple as that. But I'm sure GCC have plenty of weird, superfluous extensions to the pre-processor, so the comment seems to apply to them.

Comment: Where did you come to know that here is no evaluation of expressions during preprocessing ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Very simple: undefined macros have numeric value zero, and division by zero is illegal.

```
#if FIXEDSIZE && CHUNKSIZE/FIXEDSIZE > 42
#define USE_CELLPOOL
#endif
```

---

`#if` does evaluate the rest of its line as an integer constant expression.  Your linked documentation begins:

> The ‘#if’ directive allows you to test the value of an arithmetic expression, rather than the mere existence of one macro.

That isn't a gcc extension, the Standard's syntax for `#if` is

> `#if`*`constant-expression new-line group`<sub>`opt`</sub>*.

The C99 preprocessor treats all constants as `[u]intmax_t`.

Comment: Because if you don't have the `FIXEDSIZE` test, you get "error: division by zero in #if".  I was just about to post a very similar answer.

Comment: @haccks But is it not trivial from this example to realize the preprocessor is evaluating the division?

Comment: @MM.; Hmm. That's what the question: *There is no evaluation of expressions during preprocessing, so how can it be short-circuited?*

Comment: @haccks I see it now, you're correct. Filling in everyone else's momentary blind spot doesn't answer OP's question directly.  Fixing.

Comment: @jthill; Ahhh. At least some is here who understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: I see, so expressions are of course evaluated. But is there any example that has a side effect (and where therefor short-circuiting matters), which is not division-by-zero?

Comment: @temple `-Wundef`, as mentioned in Jeffrey Thomas's answer, although I wouldn't call that a *side effect* exactly.  But that's it.  None of the operators supported in `#if` have side effects, and identifiers on an `#if` line that are neither macros nor the tiny handful of keywords valid in `#if` (in C99 only `defined`; in C++ also things like `and`, `bitand`, `true`, and `false`; C2011 might add some more as well, don't remember)  are uniformly replaced by the constant `0`, no matter what their significance outside `#if`.

Answer (score 10):

What they are referring to is `&&` and `||` operators for `#if`

```
#if defined (AAA) || defined (BBB)
```

If `defined (AAA)` is defined then `defined (BBB)` is never evaluated.

---

**UPDATE**

So running the calculation will be short circuited. For example, if you build with `-Wundef` to warn about the usage of undefined macros.

```
#if defined FOO && FOO > 1000
#endif

#if FOO > 1000
#endif
```

will result in

```
thomas:~ jeffery$ gcc foo.c -Wundef
foo.c:4:5: warning: 'FOO' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if FOO > 1000
    ^
1 warning generated.
```

So the first version does not generate the undefined macro warning, because `FOO > 1000` is not evaluated.

---

**OLD MUSINGS**

This become important if the second part is a macro which has side effects. The macro would not be evaluated, so the side effects would not take place.

---

To avoid macro abuse I'll give a somewhat sane example

```
#define FOO
#define IF_WARN(x) _Pragma (#x) 1
#if defined(FOO) || IF_WARN(GCC warning "FOO not defined")
#endif
```

Now that I constructed this example, I now run into a problem. `IF_WARN` is always evaluated.

huh, more research needed.

---

Well foo… now that I read it again.

> Macros. All macros in the expression are expanded before actual computation of the expression's value begins.

Comment: What does it change, since the preprocessor doesn't have side effects ? Edit: seems I'm mistaken, so I'd like to see a sample :)

Comment: Macros can have side effects.

Comment: @JefferyThomas: Such as?

Comment: In what way does it not answer the question? I think it perfectly answers the question. The preprocessor expressions are - of course - evaluated by the preprocessor.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis; Then you must have standard quote about the evaluation of expression during preprocessing?

Comment: If you `#define BBB {volatile int x=0;}` then the macro contains a side effect, but that side effect is only relevant when the macro is invoked from the program, not during pre-processor evaluation. Don't mix those things up.

Comment: `defined(A)` is an expression, and `defined(A) || defined(B)` is an expression too. Of course that is evaluated (and short-circuited, like normal expressions in C), otherwise the preprocessor would not function properly. Anything that follows the `#if` is a preprocessor expression.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: The entire point of the question is asking whether it matters whether one expression is evaluated and the other isn't; this answer just teaches about what short-circuiting is, without even _attempting_ to answer the question. As for your last comment, "preprocessor expression" and "C++ expression" are two very different things, and I think it's quite clear which one the OP was referring to.

Comment: The entire point is what it means, not if it matters, AFAICT. It means that `defined(B)` is not evaluated if `defined(A)` is true. It may not matter a lot (although I have a feeling it might matter, but I must admit I can't find an example of this), but that was not the question.

Comment: I am aware of the difference between C expressions and preprocessor expressions. Not sure how that matters. `defined(BBB)` is a preprocessor expression, and it is obviously evaluated by the preprocessor (or not, in the case of short-circuit). So there is evaluation taking place during preprocessing, even if it is not the C (runtime) code that is evaluated. ISTM that that is exactly what the quoted text in the original question means. So, IMO, this answer explains exactly what the OP is asking.

Comment: FWIW, This may be interesting too (especially for GNU C): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html . Note that it says: `Macros. All macros in the expression are expanded before actual computation of the expression's value begins.`

Comment: Nice edit. Now this perfectly answer the question. Requesting people to remove their downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

> There is no evaluation of expressions during preprocessing, so how can it be short-circuited?

**Yes there is evaluation of expression during preprocessing**.

#### C11: 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion (p4):

> **Prior to evaluation**, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become ...

In a footnote 166:

> Because the **controlling constant expression is evaluated during translation phase 4**, all identifiers....

These statements clearly testify that **there is evaluation of expression in preprocessing**. The necessary condition is that the controlling expression must evaluate to an integer value.
Now the operator `&&` and `||` will obey the usual short-circuiting rules of standard C as stated in [GNU doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html).

Now run this program with and without `//` and see the result to see the short-circuit behavior:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define macro1 1
//#define macro2 1
int main( void )
{
    #if  defined (macro1)  && defined (macro2)
    printf( "Hello!\n" );
    #endif
    printf("World\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: one simple example of expanded macros in `#if` expressions: `#define VERSION 5.0 ... #if VERSION > 6.0 && defined (cplusplus)`. This does not check if cplusplus is defined at all, since the MIN_VERSION is too low anyway. And the macro is most definitely expanded into `5.0`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis; I agreed. But, what OP actually asking about the evaluation of expression not about the short-circuit behavior. (By the way I did't downvoted your answer, in general I have been stopped downvoting on answers on such a typical question).

Comment: I did not have an answer, just a few comments, so there is nothing to downvote. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis; Oops I thought you as Jeffery Thomas :P

Answer (score 3):

Evaluating macro conditions is a part (a major part) of pre-processing, so it occurs and short-circuiting is meaningful there. You can see examples of the other answers.

> A **conditional** is a directive that instructs the **preprocessor** to select
>   whether or not to include a chunk of code in the final token stream
>   passed to the compiler. **Preprocessor conditionals** can test arithmetic
>   expressions, or whether a name is defined as a macro, or both
>   simultaneously using the special defined operator.[†](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html#SEC31)

Moreover, it *can* reduce the compile time. Altering the following evaluations can speed up the compilation (depeds on implementation of a compiler).