# How to check if macro is defined and its value is true in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am working on a project that has multiple products and they all share the same code base. Each product has a `product_XXX.h` file associated with it that use `#define` directive to define macros. I would like to introduce a new macro for a **single** product only.
For example:

`#define FANCY_FEATURE   1`

In other words, I don't want to add this to all the other products and set it to zero.

Now in the code, in order for it to compile for all the projects, I need to check if it is defined. I also want to check and make sure FANCY_FEATURE is set to 1. How can I do these two steps at once.

`#if defined (FANCY_FEATURE) && (FANCY_FEATURE)` came to my mind but I wasn't sure about the order of execution (e.g.: right hand side being evaluated first) and if it would generate an error using different compilers.

Comment: Are you asking for C variables or preprocessor macros? The preprocessor has no concept of variable.

Comment: It's `defined(A)`, not `define(A)`. But you can just write `#if A`.

Comment: I recommend to provide more context on what you want to achieve. Give examples of code you intend to use this with or in. Without that I am afraid you might be tripped by a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: There's no error in the preprocessor for undefined macros, so order of evaluation is not an issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037595/is-there-logical-short-circuiting-in-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: Do you care about whether it is "true" as in the traditional C sense: non-zero, or if it is `true` like the C99 to C17 macro `true` which is defined to exactly `1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write `#if A`.

Short demo program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Try all 3 variants:

#define A 1
//#define A 0
//#undef A

int main()
{
#if defined(A) && A
  printf("defined(A) && A\n");
#endif

#if A
    printf("#if A\n");
#endif
}
```

Comment: This does not explain why it works. Just giving code and leaving it a mystery as to why it works is not a good answer.